# How to run NX tests with verbose logging?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

Running the latest version of NX and its associated dependencies:

```
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.5.4",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.5.4",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.5.4",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.5.4",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.5.4",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react": "14.5.4",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "^14.5.4",
    "@nrwl/web": "14.5.4",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.5.4",
```

I run the following command expecting to see verbose logging for my tests:

`yarn nx run-many --all --target=test --skip-nx-cache --verbose`

but no logging at all appears, and the tests appear to hang without running.

Is there a way to get verbose logging running your project in NX, or is that feature currently broken?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into your question when investigating how to get the results in my local terminal when running a custom target I made for npm audit via run-many. It used to only tell me that both of my projects succeded but I needed to see the results of the audits. For me, I needed to add:

```
 --output-style=static
```

at the end of the run-many command.

Answer (score 0):

adding a flag --reporter=verbose solves the problem